# How to hide tax from cart

Tags: magento-2.1, tax

I would like to hide the voice "Tax" in the cart summary only for one store view.

[image]

I tried changing some combination in **Admin > Configuration > Sales > Tax** but it doesn't works.

What should I have to do? Thank you so much!!

Comment: you want to using css ???

Comment: Hi Mohit, I think that via CSS I can't hide it only for one of my store view, so maybe I have to use a html or phtml file but I don't know which. Thank you.